# Adding job to crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I have a `crontab` installed on my server, which is assigned to do some jobs. Now I want to assign one more job which will be executed after the last one.

From what I learned during my research, I need to specify the file I want to execute in `/var/spool/cron/crontab/root`. But the interesting thing is that this file has a header:

> # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.

I didn't find any mention about `master` in any manual. Does it mean that I can't just put the line in the file I mentioned above and save it? I am asking before trying to do so because I am not the owner of the server and I do not want to mess it up. I have cron v5.0 installed.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: You might also be interested by the `at` and `batch` commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you just do

```
crontab -e
```

And crontab will take care of the rest....

Answer (score 2):

You do:

```
crontab -e
```

And then you're in vi mode (hit `i` to begin typing and then `esc` `:wq (enter)` to save and quit.